# How to obtain the text from site with python requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, request

I was trying to obtain info from this site: https://www.grimtools.com/db/category/components/items (description of grim dawn components).

Using a simple requests.get([url](https://www.grimtools.com/db/category/components/items)) I just got this: (picture from chrome devtools)
[image]

I was able to solve my problem getting the info from another site, but I wanted to learn more about requests.
**I can see the text I want is in the source code of the site, but how to obtain it?**

More specifically, I want each 'class="item-description"' inside of 'class="item-list-group"':

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The page doesn't actually contain the data you're looking for.

If you use `requests` to `.get` the URL and inspect the result you will see it differs from what you see in devtools.

Chrome executes the javascript on the item page which then initiates more http requests.

You can use the [devtools search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmmjB.png) to search the content of requests.

I searched for the [first item description on the page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r00uG.png)

[image]

Which tells us the data is coming from:

> https://www.grimtools.com/db/itemdb/l10n/en.js

When using `requests` it doesn't execute javascript, so these extra http requests are not made.

But now that you have the URL, you can `.get` it directly.

The response is a "javascript variable", however, if you remove everything before the first `=` and remove the trailing `;` it is then valid json.

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.grimtools.com/db/itemdb/l10n/en.js')

data = json.loads(r.content[r.content.find(b"=") + 1:].strip(b";"))
```

The response is quite large, so pretty printing it and saving it to a file is helpful.

```
with open("data.json", "w") as f: 
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4), file=f)
```

First few lines:

```
───────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: data.json
───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ {
   2   │   "tagEnemySkillD02": "Fire Devil",
   3   │   "tagTrollHeroH01": "Uglak, the Immortal",
   4   │   "tagEnemySkillD01": "Entropic Void",
   5   │   "tagTrollHeroH02": "Surrlak, the Earthmover",
   6   │   "tagTrollHeroH03": "Troglak ~ Unstoppable",
```